# Probability of beginning with 3 lands on initial hand in Magic: the Gathering

Tags: probability

I am a Magic: the Gathering player and I want to understand the logic and the statistics behind the game.

Let me explain the basics:
A deck contains 60 cards and there is about a third part of those cards need to be land type. (This proportion varies with the type of deck.)

My first question is how to calculate the probability of a starting hand that contains Y (by default 7) cards to have X lands on it (1, 2, 3, etc...).

I assume that after that, with 1 draw each turn the probability of drawing a land type is total_lands - lands in hand divided by the numbers of cards left as it is an independent event, but I might be wrong.

EDIT: Thanks to approbed solution I did the computations and they seem to be well:

```
from scipy.special import comb
import numpy as np


def compute(desired_lands_in_starting_hand: int, total_land_cards: int, hand_size: int, deck_size: int = 60):
    print(f" Composition of experiment ---> \nYou want {desired_lands_in_starting_hand} lands in {hand_size} cards starting hand")
    print(f"With a total of {total_land_cards} land cards in your {deck_size} cards deck \n")
    k, N, K, n = desired_lands_in_starting_hand, deck_size, total_land_cards, hand_size 
    probability = (comb(K, k, exact=True) * comb(N-K, n-k, exact=True)) / comb(N, n, exact=True)
    print(f" Resulting probability is ---> {np.round(probability, 4) * 100} %")

compute(3, 23, 7, 60)
```

Comment: A deck must contain *at least* 60 cards in standard format (with optional 15 card sideboard), just being pedantic. As to why include more than 60 see [Why would you want to play with a deck bigger than 60 cards in MTG?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/179/why-would-you-want-to-play-with-a-deck-bigger-than-60-cards-in-mtg#)

Comment: @JonnyHenly A bit pedantic you are being hahaha. I just play Pioneer and the constraint is 60+ I think. But the question you are pointing me to gives detailed explanations of these questions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note you can do `from math import comb` instead of `from scipy.special import comb`. This will take `comb` from the standard library instead of from the additional library scipy. And then you don't need the `exact=True` argument, as `math.comb` never makes approximations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I remember dabbling with a similar question in the past!
You are looking for the probability of success of WITHOUT replacement: the hyper-geometric distribution [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

You can obtain the probability distribution of getting exactly $k$ successes over $n$ trials (size of your hand) in a population $N$ (your deck size) with $K$ positive outcomes (number of lands). You can do this with suitable programming languages (R, python, Matlab, Stata, Julia...)

If you are not familiar with programming, I think you can find some hypergeometric calculators online as well. I don't want to give you a solution, as I think this is a funny problem to get your hands dirty!

Here is a nice article to dive even deeper: [link](https://strategy.channelfireball.com/all-strategy/mtg/channelmagic-articles/how-many-lands-do-you-need-to-consistently-hit-your-land-drops/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will read it deeply in an hour maybe and try to do the computation. I am very exprienced in Python! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped, good job implementing a solution!

Answer (score 10):

Depending on the ordering of the cards in your pre-shuffled deck, and how well you shuffle the deck, it may be reasonable to assume that your draw is a [simple random sample without replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample).  This means that any possible hand of cards in your deck is equally likely to occur.  Note that this assumption might be wrong in some circumstances --- e.g., if your pre-shuffled deck has clumps of lands and you don't shuffle it very well then your draw would not be a simple random sample.

Now, assuming you give it a "good shuffle", such that you are willing to assume that the draw is a simple random sample, the number of lands in the draw will follow a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  In a typical game of MTG you have a deck of $N=60$ cards containing $K$ lands and you draw an initial hand of $n=7$ cards.  Let $X$ denote the number of lands in your opening hand.  Then the probability of drawing exactly $x$ lands in the opening hand is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X=x) 
&= \text{Hyper}(x|N=60,K,n=7) \\[12pt]
&= \frac{{K \choose x} {60-K \choose 7-x}}{{60 \choose 7}} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{386206920} {K \choose x} {60-K \choose 7-x}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

We can use this distribution to compute the relevant probabilities for all possible decks of size $N=60$ drawing $n=7$ cards.  Below I compute a matrix containing all the relevant probabilities.  The rows show the number of lands in the deck and the columns show the number of lands drawn.  This was computed in `R` using the [`dhyper`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Hypergeometric.html) function for the hypergeometric distribution.

```
#Set deck size and draw size
N <- 60
n <- 7

#Generate probability matrix
PROBMATRIX <- matrix(0, nrow = N+1, ncol = n+1)
rownames(PROBMATRIX) <- sprintf('Land[%s]', 0:N)
colnames(PROBMATRIX) <- sprintf('Draw[%s]', 0:n)
for (k in 0:N) { PROBMATRIX[k+1, ] <- dhyper(0:n, m = k, n = N-k, k = n) }

#Print probability matrix (to four DP)
round(PROBMATRIX, 4)

         Draw[0] Draw[1] Draw[2] Draw[3] Draw[4] Draw[5] Draw[6] Draw[7]
Land[0]   1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
Land[1]   0.8833  0.1167  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
Land[2]   0.7785  0.2096  0.0119  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
Land[3]   0.6846  0.2819  0.0325  0.0010  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
Land[4]   0.6005  0.3363  0.0593  0.0038  0.0001  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
Land[5]   0.5254  0.3753  0.0901  0.0088  0.0003  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
Land[6]   0.4586  0.4012  0.1228  0.0164  0.0010  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
Land[7]   0.3991  0.4161  0.1560  0.0265  0.0021  0.0001  0.0000  0.0000
Land[8]   0.3464  0.4217  0.1884  0.0393  0.0040  0.0002  0.0000  0.0000
Land[9]   0.2998  0.4197  0.2190  0.0544  0.0068  0.0004  0.0000  0.0000
Land[10]  0.2586  0.4115  0.2469  0.0716  0.0107  0.0008  0.0000  0.0000
Land[11]  0.2224  0.3983  0.2716  0.0905  0.0157  0.0014  0.0001  0.0000
Land[12]  0.1906  0.3813  0.2926  0.1108  0.0222  0.0023  0.0001  0.0000
Land[13]  0.1628  0.3614  0.3098  0.1321  0.0300  0.0036  0.0002  0.0000
Land[14]  0.1386  0.3395  0.3230  0.1538  0.0393  0.0054  0.0004  0.0000
Land[15]  0.1175  0.3163  0.3322  0.1755  0.0502  0.0077  0.0006  0.0000
Land[16]  0.0992  0.2924  0.3374  0.1968  0.0624  0.0107  0.0009  0.0000
Land[17]  0.0834  0.2684  0.3390  0.2173  0.0761  0.0145  0.0014  0.0001
Land[18]  0.0699  0.2445  0.3370  0.2365  0.0910  0.0191  0.0020  0.0001
Land[19]  0.0582  0.2212  0.3318  0.2541  0.1070  0.0247  0.0029  0.0001
Land[20]  0.0483  0.1988  0.3237  0.2698  0.1239  0.0313  0.0040  0.0002
Land[21]  0.0398  0.1774  0.3131  0.2833  0.1416  0.0390  0.0055  0.0003
Land[22]  0.0327  0.1573  0.3002  0.2943  0.1598  0.0479  0.0073  0.0004
Land[23]  0.0267  0.1384  0.2856  0.3029  0.1782  0.0580  0.0097  0.0006
Land[24]  0.0216  0.1210  0.2694  0.3087  0.1964  0.0693  0.0125  0.0009
Land[25]  0.0174  0.1051  0.2522  0.3118  0.2144  0.0819  0.0160  0.0012
Land[26]  0.0139  0.0905  0.2342  0.3122  0.2316  0.0956  0.0203  0.0017
Land[27]  0.0111  0.0774  0.2157  0.3099  0.2479  0.1104  0.0253  0.0023
Land[28]  0.0087  0.0657  0.1971  0.3050  0.2630  0.1262  0.0312  0.0031
Land[29]  0.0068  0.0553  0.1786  0.2977  0.2764  0.1430  0.0381  0.0040
Land[30]  0.0053  0.0461  0.1605  0.2881  0.2881  0.1605  0.0461  0.0053
Land[31]  0.0040  0.0381  0.1430  0.2764  0.2977  0.1786  0.0553  0.0068
Land[32]  0.0031  0.0312  0.1262  0.2630  0.3050  0.1971  0.0657  0.0087
Land[33]  0.0023  0.0253  0.1104  0.2479  0.3099  0.2157  0.0774  0.0111
Land[34]  0.0017  0.0203  0.0956  0.2316  0.3122  0.2342  0.0905  0.0139
Land[35]  0.0012  0.0160  0.0819  0.2144  0.3118  0.2522  0.1051  0.0174
Land[36]  0.0009  0.0125  0.0693  0.1964  0.3087  0.2694  0.1210  0.0216
Land[37]  0.0006  0.0097  0.0580  0.1782  0.3029  0.2856  0.1384  0.0267
Land[38]  0.0004  0.0073  0.0479  0.1598  0.2943  0.3002  0.1573  0.0327
Land[39]  0.0003  0.0055  0.0390  0.1416  0.2833  0.3131  0.1774  0.0398
Land[40]  0.0002  0.0040  0.0313  0.1239  0.2698  0.3237  0.1988  0.0483
Land[41]  0.0001  0.0029  0.0247  0.1070  0.2541  0.3318  0.2212  0.0582
Land[42]  0.0001  0.0020  0.0191  0.0910  0.2365  0.3370  0.2445  0.0699
Land[43]  0.0001  0.0014  0.0145  0.0761  0.2173  0.3390  0.2684  0.0834
Land[44]  0.0000  0.0009  0.0107  0.0624  0.1968  0.3374  0.2924  0.0992
Land[45]  0.0000  0.0006  0.0077  0.0502  0.1755  0.3322  0.3163  0.1175
Land[46]  0.0000  0.0004  0.0054  0.0393  0.1538  0.3230  0.3395  0.1386
Land[47]  0.0000  0.0002  0.0036  0.0300  0.1321  0.3098  0.3614  0.1628
Land[48]  0.0000  0.0001  0.0023  0.0222  0.1108  0.2926  0.3813  0.1906
Land[49]  0.0000  0.0001  0.0014  0.0157  0.0905  0.2716  0.3983  0.2224
Land[50]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0008  0.0107  0.0716  0.2469  0.4115  0.2586
Land[51]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0004  0.0068  0.0544  0.2190  0.4197  0.2998
Land[52]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0002  0.0040  0.0393  0.1884  0.4217  0.3464
Land[53]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0001  0.0021  0.0265  0.1560  0.4161  0.3991
Land[54]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0010  0.0164  0.1228  0.4012  0.4586
Land[55]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0003  0.0088  0.0901  0.3753  0.5254
Land[56]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0001  0.0038  0.0593  0.3363  0.6005
Land[57]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0010  0.0325  0.2819  0.6846
Land[58]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0119  0.2096  0.7785
Land[59]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.1167  0.8833
Land[60]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  1.0000
```

When looking at the probabilities of getting a particular number of lands, it is also worth noting that MTG rules allow players to take a "mulligan", whereby they redraw their hand if they do not like their original hand.  There are various [rules variations](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Mulligan) for different types of mulligan and different strategies players can use when deciding to take a mulligan.  These lead to different probabilities for the number of lands in the final hand.  The mulligan rule gives players some safety if they draw an opening hand with to few lands, so as a general principle, it operates to decrease the probability of getting "too few" lands.

---

**When do you run out of land?** As you are no doubt aware, the rules of MTG allow a player to play one land each turn, subject to some special cards that vary this.  Consequently, a more useful statistical question for checking for sufficient land in MTG is to find the distribution of *the number of turns it takes a player to run out of land* and therefore be unable to play a land in their turn.  In most situtions this is the more useful question for determining how many land should be included in a deck.

This question requires some assumptions to calculate well (e.g., assuming player draws only one card per turn, no fetch-lands, etc.).  Suppose the player has an initial draw of $d+1$ cards for the first turn and then draws one additional card each turn, with no other draw or search effects, etc.  Let $X_n$ denote the number of lands drawn in the first $n$ cards and define the variable:

$$T = \min \{ n = 1,2,3,... | X_{d+n} < n \}.$$

The random variable $T$ is the first turn at which the player is unable to play a land.  Then we have the equivalence $\mathbb{P}(T > t) = \mathbb{P}(X_{d+t} \geqslant t)$ which then gives the probability mass function:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(T = t) 
&= \mathbb{P}(T > t-1) - \mathbb{P}(T > t) \\[16pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(X_{d+t-1} \geqslant t-1) - \mathbb{P}(X_{d+t} \geqslant t) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{x=t-1}^{\min(d+t-1,K)} \text{Hyper}(x|N=60,K,d+t-1) \\[6pt]
&\quad - \sum_{x=t}^{\min(d+t,K)} \text{Hyper}(x|N=60,K,d+t). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

We can use the hypergeometric distribution to compute the relevant probabilities for all possible decks of size $N=60$ drawing $n=7$ cards and then drawing one additional card each turn (so we have eight cards by the end of the first turn).  Below I compute a matrix containing all the relevant probabilities.  The rows show the number of lands in the deck and the columns show the first turn in which the player has no land left to play.  (If you want to get the probabilities for a player who does not draw a card in the first turn, all you need to do is reduce `d` by one in this calculation.)

```
#Set deck size, initial draw and maximum turn value of interest
#At first turn we have d+1 cards
N     <- 60
d     <- 7
max.t <- 20

#Generate probability matrix
PROBTURN <- matrix(0, nrow = N+1, ncol = max.t)
rownames(PROBTURN ) <- sprintf('Land[%s]', 0:N)
colnames(PROBTURN ) <- sprintf('Turn[%s]', 1:max.t)
for (k in 0:N) { 
for (t in 1:max.t) { 
   if (t == 1) {
     PROBTURN [k+1, t] <- dhyper(0, m = k, n = N-k, k = d+1)  }
   if (t > 1) {
     PROBTURN [k+1, t] <- phyper(t-2, m = k, n = N-k, k = d+t-1, lower.tail = FALSE) -
                            phyper(t-1, m = k, n = N-k, k = d+t, lower.tail = FALSE) } } }

#Print probability matrix (to four DP)
round(PROBTURN[, 1:10], 4)

         Turn[1] Turn[2] Turn[3] Turn[4] Turn[5] Turn[6] Turn[7] Turn[8] Turn[9] Turn[10]
Land[0]   1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[1]   0.8667  0.1333  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[2]   0.7492  0.2305  0.0203  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[3]   0.6458  0.2981  0.0526  0.0035  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[4]   0.5552  0.3416  0.0904  0.0121  0.0007  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[5]   0.4759  0.3661  0.1292  0.0258  0.0029  0.0001  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[6]   0.4067  0.3754  0.1656  0.0442  0.0074  0.0007  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[7]   0.3464  0.3731  0.1975  0.0658  0.0148  0.0022  0.0002  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[8]   0.2941  0.3620  0.2236  0.0894  0.0251  0.0050  0.0007  0.0001  0.0000   0.0000
Land[9]   0.2489  0.3446  0.2432  0.1135  0.0382  0.0096  0.0018  0.0002  0.0000   0.0000
Land[10]  0.2098  0.3228  0.2564  0.1367  0.0537  0.0161  0.0037  0.0006  0.0001   0.0000
Land[11]  0.1763  0.2983  0.2632  0.1579  0.0709  0.0248  0.0069  0.0015  0.0002   0.0000
Land[12]  0.1475  0.2723  0.2643  0.1762  0.0890  0.0356  0.0115  0.0030  0.0006   0.0001
Land[13]  0.1229  0.2458  0.2603  0.1909  0.1071  0.0482  0.0178  0.0054  0.0014   0.0003
Land[14]  0.1020  0.2197  0.2520  0.2016  0.1244  0.0622  0.0258  0.0090  0.0026   0.0006
Land[15]  0.0842  0.1944  0.2402  0.2081  0.1402  0.0771  0.0355  0.0139  0.0046   0.0013
Land[16]  0.0693  0.1705  0.2257  0.2106  0.1537  0.0922  0.0468  0.0203  0.0076   0.0025
Land[17]  0.0567  0.1482  0.2093  0.2093  0.1644  0.1069  0.0591  0.0283  0.0118   0.0043
Land[18]  0.0461  0.1277  0.1916  0.2044  0.1721  0.1204  0.0722  0.0377  0.0173   0.0070
Land[19]  0.0373  0.1092  0.1734  0.1965  0.1764  0.1323  0.0854  0.0483  0.0241   0.0107
Land[20]  0.0301  0.0925  0.1550  0.1861  0.1775  0.1420  0.0982  0.0598  0.0324   0.0157
Land[21]  0.0240  0.0777  0.1371  0.1737  0.1754  0.1491  0.1100  0.0717  0.0418   0.0220
Land[22]  0.0191  0.0647  0.1199  0.1598  0.1704  0.1534  0.1202  0.0836  0.0523   0.0296
Land[23]  0.0151  0.0534  0.1036  0.1451  0.1629  0.1547  0.1284  0.0949  0.0633   0.0383
Land[24]  0.0118  0.0437  0.0886  0.1300  0.1532  0.1532  0.1342  0.1050  0.0744   0.0481
Land[25]  0.0092  0.0354  0.0749  0.1149  0.1418  0.1489  0.1373  0.1134  0.0851   0.0584
Land[26]  0.0071  0.0284  0.0626  0.1002  0.1293  0.1422  0.1377  0.1197  0.0948   0.0689
Land[27]  0.0054  0.0225  0.0517  0.0862  0.1161  0.1335  0.1354  0.1236  0.1030   0.0791
Land[28]  0.0041  0.0177  0.0422  0.0731  0.1026  0.1231  0.1305  0.1249  0.1093   0.0883
Land[29]  0.0031  0.0138  0.0340  0.0612  0.0893  0.1116  0.1234  0.1234  0.1132   0.0960
Land[30]  0.0023  0.0106  0.0270  0.0504  0.0764  0.0993  0.1145  0.1195  0.1145   0.1018
Land[31]  0.0017  0.0080  0.0212  0.0409  0.0643  0.0869  0.1041  0.1132  0.1132   0.1052
Land[32]  0.0012  0.0060  0.0164  0.0327  0.0532  0.0745  0.0928  0.1049  0.1093   0.1059
Land[33]  0.0009  0.0044  0.0124  0.0257  0.0433  0.0628  0.0810  0.0951  0.1030   0.1041
Land[34]  0.0006  0.0032  0.0093  0.0198  0.0345  0.0518  0.0692  0.0843  0.0948   0.0996
Land[35]  0.0004  0.0023  0.0068  0.0150  0.0270  0.0418  0.0578  0.0729  0.0851   0.0928
Land[36]  0.0003  0.0016  0.0049  0.0111  0.0206  0.0330  0.0472  0.0616  0.0744   0.0841
Land[37]  0.0002  0.0011  0.0035  0.0081  0.0154  0.0255  0.0376  0.0506  0.0633   0.0741
Land[38]  0.0001  0.0007  0.0024  0.0057  0.0112  0.0191  0.0291  0.0405  0.0523   0.0633
Land[39]  0.0001  0.0005  0.0016  0.0039  0.0080  0.0140  0.0219  0.0314  0.0418   0.0524
Land[40]  0.0000  0.0003  0.0010  0.0026  0.0055  0.0099  0.0159  0.0235  0.0324   0.0419
Land[41]  0.0000  0.0002  0.0007  0.0017  0.0036  0.0067  0.0112  0.0170  0.0241   0.0322
Land[42]  0.0000  0.0001  0.0004  0.0011  0.0023  0.0044  0.0076  0.0118  0.0173   0.0237
Land[43]  0.0000  0.0001  0.0002  0.0006  0.0014  0.0028  0.0049  0.0079  0.0118   0.0167
Land[44]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0001  0.0004  0.0008  0.0017  0.0030  0.0049  0.0076   0.0111
Land[45]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0001  0.0002  0.0005  0.0009  0.0017  0.0029  0.0046   0.0069
Land[46]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0001  0.0002  0.0005  0.0009  0.0016  0.0026   0.0040
Land[47]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0001  0.0002  0.0005  0.0008  0.0014   0.0021
Land[48]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0001  0.0002  0.0004  0.0006   0.0010
Land[49]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0001  0.0001  0.0002   0.0004
Land[50]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0001   0.0001
Land[51]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[52]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[53]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[54]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[55]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[56]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[57]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[58]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[59]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
Land[60]  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.0000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer @Ben. I got to the same results. I completelly agree that the interesting question is "which is the probabilty I have of having at least 3 lands on my third turn" but I assume that is a more difficult question and I need to begin from the basics. I am thinking now of how to compute this question. I might keep asking for that question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I did these same calculations sometime back in 2012-2016 for the same purpose as the OP. And yet I have nothing to add (+1).

Comment: "which is the probabilty I have of having at least 3 lands on my third turn".  It's *mostly* just doing the same math but replacing the 7 with (9 or) 10 depending on whether or not you were on the play or draw on turn 1.  You can make it more complicated if you factor in draw card effects though

Comment: @DeanMacGregor That is indeed the important question to solve. I have made the computations via the scipy function and using mine function and in both cases probability of have 3 lands in turn 3 is higher on the play (9 cards on t3) than on the draw (10 cards on t3) for 22 lands and 7 size starting hand with 60 cards on deck. I do not understand this result. Do you know why?

Comment: I have added additional analysis of the run-out-of-lands question.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Seeing the other answer and plugging in the numbers, my result is completely wrong. I'll leave this answer here just so that someone may possibly explain where I went wrong!**

I'm nowhere near a pro statistician, and there are probably better explanations and smarter ways of doing this, but this is my attempt.

Let's say one third of your cards are lands, so out of 60 cards you have 20 lands. In an initial hand of 7 cards, there are 35 combinations of the positions in which the 3 lands can be found:
[image]

For example, you could draw 3 lands in the first three cards, in which case the probability would be:
[image]

The first term tells that we have 20 available lands out of 60 cards. Once we draw the first card and it is a land, then for the second card we have 19 lands available and 59 cards in the deck, and so on. This case is the least probable case because of the amount of other cards left in the deck. By analogy we can get the case with the largest probability, which is the case where the last three cards are lands:
[image]

And so there are 33 more combinations which give different probabilities. Now, I tried this in excel and saw that the probabilities are log-normally distributed. Here someone with a better understanding can give a theoretical explanation why it is so. Anyhow, this property tells us that we can get the median of all the 35 values by taking the geometric mean:
[image]

If the probabilities are normally distributed in the logarithmic space, then we can find the mean by taking the average of the logarithm of the minimum and maximum probabilities, or equivalently the geometric mean of the log-normally distributed values:
[image]

This is practically the same value as the calculated median from all the 35 values I got in excel, with the difference starting at the 6th decimal place. However there is a difference in the 5th decimal place between calculating the median using excel `median()` function and taking the `geomean()` of the values. Now I'm guessing, but this may be caused by the difference between discrete and continuous distributions.

I hope this makes sense and that I didn't break too much statistical rules with my assumptions! Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The probabilities -- no matter what you're trying to refer to, which is unclear -- are not lognormally distributed.